# Android recyclerview in a recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am building an app for a school project, what I want is making a week planner for students in my app. For that I need to add a recyclerview in a recyclerview item, but when I run my app it shows nothing. I think this is the error in

logcat:`06-19 15:43:36.926    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout.` Here is my code:

PlannerActivity.java

```
//day planner monday
    ArrayList<DayItems> mon = new ArrayList<>();
    mon.add(new DayItems("huiswerk maken"));

    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dayitems, viewGroup);

    RecyclerView dayPlan = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.mon);
    dayPlan.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    dayPlan.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    DayRecAdapter dayAdapter = new DayRecAdapter(mon);
    dayPlan.setAdapter(dayAdapter);

    //planner
    RecyclerView plan = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.planner);
    plan.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    plan.setLayoutManager(linManager);

    PlannerRecAdapter recAdapter = new PlannerRecAdapter(R.layout.dayitems);
    plan.setAdapter(recAdapter);
```

Both of the adapters for my agenda:

adapter of todo list which is inside a recyclerview item:

```
public class DayRecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DayViewHolder> {

ArrayList<DayItems> mList;

public DayRecAdapter(ArrayList<DayItems> mList){
    this.mList = mList;
}

public int getItemCount(){
    return mList.size();
}

public DayViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planitem, viewGroup, false);
    DayViewHolder DVH = new DayViewHolder(v);
    return DVH;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(DayViewHolder vHolder, int i){
    vHolder.dayText.setText(mList.get(i).todo);
}

}
```

Adapter of the main recyclerview:

```
public class PlannerRecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlannerViewHolder> {

int layoutResource;

public PlannerRecAdapter(int layoutResource){
    this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
}

public int getItemCount(){
    return 1;
}

public PlannerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(layoutResource, viewGroup, false);
    PlannerViewHolder PVH = new PlannerViewHolder(v);
    return PVH;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(PlannerViewHolder holder, int i){

}
}
```

And here is the layout resource of PlannerRecAdapter:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/planCard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#9CCC65"
        android:layout_margin="13dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dagTXT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text2"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:text="Maandag"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Logcat:

```
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING
06-19 15:43:34.142    2980-3015/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
06-19 15:43:34.184    2980-3013/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(318)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
06-19 15:43:34.220    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-19 15:43:34.235    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
06-19 15:43:34.350    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
06-19 15:43:34.359    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-19 15:43:34.417    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-19 15:43:34.423    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-19 15:43:34.576    2980-3046/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
06-19 15:43:34.576    2980-3046/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
06-19 15:43:34.622    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
06-19 15:43:34.622    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
06-19 15:43:34.884    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2980
06-19 15:43:36.742    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-19 15:43:36.926    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-19 15:43:41.519    2980-2991/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
06-19 15:59:14.349    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-19 15:59:14.355    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
06-19 15:59:14.684    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2980
06-19 15:59:14.902    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
06-19 15:59:14.902    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
06-19 15:59:21.278    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-19 15:59:21.284    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
06-19 15:59:21.527    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2980
06-19 15:59:21.809    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
06-19 15:59:21.809    2980-3030/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
06-19 15:59:25.131    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-19 15:59:25.182    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layo
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post the entire logcat

Comment: This is my Logcat:`06-19 15:43:36.742    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-19 15:43:36.926    2980-2980/com.sapps.tools.dedykapp E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout`. I don't actually know what to do with this logcat

Comment: I mean the entire logcat. Update your question with the entire logcat.

Comment: added logcat to my question!

Comment: seems like it's not an error. Does your app crash?

Comment: No it doesn't it just doesn't show anything where my recyclerview is

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In Your PlannerActivity.java   Declare

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter  adapter
```

Then in your onCreate  method, find it like this.

```
adapter = new DayRecAdapter(mon);
```

Hope this will solve the no adapter attached issue

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, you need to set the adapter `prior` to setting the LayoutManager.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lManager);
```

I'm not sure if you can set your inner adapter like that.
 I set it in the  constructor of the outer RecyclerView's ViewHolder.